# Laravel hasManyThrough returns empty result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a 3 tables: **Chats**, **Messages**, **Invoices**

[image]

Before, I got chat invoices like this:

```
//ChatModel:
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
}
```

But now I need to get all chat invoices **which present in chat messages** of specific chat. Should I use hasManyThrough for this? Unfortunately, the next example returns an empty result

```
//ChatModel:
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Invoice::class, Message::class, 'chat_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: I think the last parameter of the relationship should also be `chat_id`, which is the foreign key on invoices table. Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have both chat_id and invoice_id in your messages table you should just your messages table as a pivot table !

```php
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class, 'messages');
}
```

Comment: So easy and pretty solution. Thanks!